# Splitting string data into keywords in Python in customized order and store specific keywords separately

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I have a message like

```
 message= "Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016"
```

I need **2 arrays** out of this message one should be **words** which is split words and (not hashtags) only **before occurrence of the second hashtag** and no need to store the rest of words after the second hashtag as key words, like:

```
key words:`['Hello','I','am','in']`
```

also I need to store all the hashtags in their occurrence orders in the message:

```
tags: `['#world','#London','#sunny','#2016']`
```

to split words before occurrence of second hashtag I am using the following code:

```
i=message.find("#",str(row[0]).find("#")+1)
words=re.sub(r'[)|*&$^(;!][,]', r' ',(message)[:i])).split()
```

the problem is that in this case I still have first hashtag in the words!?

Also I need to build an array like tags in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses `itertools.groupby` from the std lib:

```
from itertools import groupby

is_hashtag = lambda w: w.startswith('#') and len(w)>1

tests = """\
    Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016
    Hello #London I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016
    Hello #Austin I am at #SXSW and this is just a # hashtag symbol"""

for t in tests.splitlines():
    t = t.strip()
    groups = groupby(t.split(), key=is_hashtag)

    tags = []
    keywords = []

    # get words up to first hashtag
    ishash, words = next(groups)
    keywords.extend(list(words))

    # get first hashtag
    ishash, tag = next(groups)
    tags.extend(list(tag))

    # get words up to next hashtag
    ishash, words = next(groups)
    keywords.extend(list(words))

    # get all remaining hashtags
    for ishash, tag in groups:
        if ishash:
            newtags = list(tag)
            tags.extend(newtags)

    print (t)
    print (tags)
    print (keywords)
    print ('')
```

The key function toggles the grouping state, returning all words that are not hashtags, or all words that are hashtags.

Prints:

```
Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016
['#world', '#London', '#sunny', '#2016']
['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'in']

Hello #London I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016
['#London', '#London', '#sunny', '#2016']
['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'in']

Hello #Austin I am at #SXSW and this is just a # hashtag symbol
['#Austin', '#SXSW']
['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'at']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the only problem is that this method can not notice hashtags if they are the very first word of the messages, like if it was "#Hello #worlds I am ..." !!

Comment: Cleaning up the logic is left as an exercise for the question poster

Comment: As a tip, the boolean value of `ishash` will tell you whether the current list of words are hashtags or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of regex. The algorithm for this is

- Split the message into parts and using a list comprehension filter the tags
- Using the second tag, cut the first message
- Again using list comprehension, find the key words.

---

```
>>> message= "Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016"
>>> tags = [i for i in message.split() if i[0]=='#']
>>> temp_message = message.split(tags[1])[0]
>>> key_words = [i for i in temp_message.split() if i[0]!='#']
>>> tags
['#world', '#London', '#sunny', '#2016']
>>> key_words
['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'in']
```

Comment: Thanks how can I split rather than white space also with other characters like '[)|*&$^(;!][,]' in this case?

Comment: @Farimah Read the linked doc, it'll be of more use  ... You can use `split('[')` i.e, pass a parameter to the `split` function  :-)

Comment: Hah, Happens. Not a problem. Glad to be of help to you.

Comment: Using list comprehension is so Pythonic but having to iterate over the same elements twice is not brilliant :/

Comment: Hmm, @ERodriguez We iterate over `message` in the first listcomp and `temp_message` in the second. Not sure if I got your point exactly

Comment: Alright, it's not the same list. But I think it could be more perfomance-friendly

Answer (score 1):

One might think a parser is overkill for this problem, but if you use one, then you will be better able to handle the inevitable "oh, there is one more minor variation on the format" changes that will come along.

Here is a pyparsing solution to your question:

```
from pyparsing import Word, printables, ZeroOrMore, OneOrMore

hashword = Word('#', printables, min=2)("hashtag*")
word = ~hashword + Word(printables)

msg = (ZeroOrMore(word)("leading") + 
        hashword + 
        OneOrMore(word)("internal") + 
        hashword + 
        ZeroOrMore(hashword | word)("trailing"))


tests = """\
    Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016
    Hello #London I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016
    Hello #Austin I am at #SXSW and this is just a # hashtag symbol"""

msg.runTests(tests)

# show how to access the named results in the parsed output
for t in tests.splitlines():
    fields = msg.parseString(t)
    print(fields.hashtag)
```

`hashword` defines a word that starts with a '#', and has at least one additional character. The `("hashtag*")` will serve to collect all the hashtags in the message into a single result name. `word` defines a word of any characters, so long as it is not a `hashword`. The `msg` definition defines all the pieces of the message that you specified, and assigns the different pieces to the names `leading`, `internal`, and `trailing`.

Finally, the little for-loop at the end shows how to access the different named results returned from the call to `parseString()`.

Here is what this outputs:

```
Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016
['Hello', '#world', 'I', 'am', 'in', '#London', 'and', 'it', 'is', '#sunny', 'today', 'it', 'is', '#2016']
- hashtag: ['#world', '#London', '#sunny', '#2016']
- internal: ['I', 'am', 'in']
- leading: ['Hello']
- trailing: ['and', 'it', 'is', '#sunny', 'today', 'it', 'is', '#2016']
  - hashtag: ['#sunny', '#2016']

Hello #London I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016
['Hello', '#London', 'I', 'am', 'in', '#London', 'and', 'it', 'is', '#sunny', 'today', 'it', 'is', '#2016']
- hashtag: ['#London', '#London', '#sunny', '#2016']
- internal: ['I', 'am', 'in']
- leading: ['Hello']
- trailing: ['and', 'it', 'is', '#sunny', 'today', 'it', 'is', '#2016']
  - hashtag: ['#sunny', '#2016']

Hello #Austin I am at #SXSW and this is just a # hashtag symbol
['Hello', '#Austin', 'I', 'am', 'at', '#SXSW', 'and', 'this', 'is', 'just', 'a', '#', 'hashtag', 'symbol']
- hashtag: ['#Austin', '#SXSW']
- internal: ['I', 'am', 'at']
- leading: ['Hello']
- trailing: ['and', 'this', 'is', 'just', 'a', '#', 'hashtag', 'symbol']

['#world', '#London', '#sunny', '#2016']
['#London', '#London', '#sunny', '#2016']
['#NewYork', '#SXSW']
```

**EDIT**

If you aren't sure that the input string actually contains hashtags and words in the form you describe, you can extend the parser definition to accept pretty much any combination of hashtags and words as a fallback:

```
msg = (ZeroOrMore(word)("leading") + 
        hashword + 
        OneOrMore(word)("internal") + 
        hashword + 
        ZeroOrMore(hashword | word)("trailing") 
       |
       # use this expression to just get whatever hashtags are to be found
       OneOrMore(hashword | word))
```

The second part of the parser will just gather all the hashtags into the 'hashtag' result name, and the other names ('leading', etc.) will be undefined.

Comment: thanks I am trying to apply your code and I am facing this error: "AttributeError: 'And' object has no attribute 'runTests' " as you may guess I am pretty new in Python , it is not clear to me why I am facing it here?

Comment: runTests was added in a recent version of pyparsing.  Make sure you are using the latest release, using `pip install -U pyparsing`

Comment: This error is that the parser is looking for a hashtag (a word starting with '#', followed by printables), and getting as far as column 829 and not finding one! I suspect that this is a very long input line, and that it does not conform to your expected format.  Print out the line it is failing on, and make sure there are at least 2 hashtags in it.

Comment: This error is that the parser is looking for a hashtag (a word starting with '#', followed by printables), and getting as far as column 829 and not finding one! I suspect that this is a very long input line, and that it does not conform to your expected format. Print out the line it is failing on, and make sure there are at least 2 hashtags in it.

Comment: yes in fact there might be tweets in my data set that might have no or only one hashtag, may be they are the problem , can I access to, for example ith hashtags just by calling hashtag[i] in this case?

Comment: If they don't conform to your format, what do you want to do with them? Where will you get the keywords from? But yes, `fields.hashtag` will give you a list-like structure that you can use just like it was a list (use [] indexing, call len(), etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to control the process using conditional statements or something like try/exception! meanwhile I am also trying to check the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would first split the String into a list of words and then iterate over those words, appending the words in the right list (using **startswith()** function):

```
message_list = message.split()
tags = []
notags = []
for e in message_list:
    if e.startswith('#'):
        tags.append(e)
    else:
        notags.append(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

```
import re

string = "Hello #world I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016"

#get hash tags only list
list_hash_tags = re.findall(r'#\S+', string)
print(list_hash_tags)

#use second element in hash tag list to get string match up to second match
list_keywords_step0 = re.findall(r'^.*?(?=' + list_hash_tags[1] + r')', string)
list_keywords_step0[0] = re.sub(r'#\w+\W+', '', list_keywords_step0[0])

#get keywords
list_keywords = list_keywords_step0[0].split()
print(list_keywords)
```

Output:

```
['#world', '#London', '#sunny', '#2016']
['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'in']
```

Comment: What if the input string is "Hello #London I am in #London and it is #sunny today it is #2016" ?

Comment: Unfortunately, since the first and second hashtags are the same, your call to `re.findall` to get the second tag actually finds the first, so your list of keywords contains just `['Hello']`, not `['Hello', 'I', 'am', 'in']`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire - you are right, thanks for the test. - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5757880/deepak-nagarajan)